# Agregar iconos de Bootstrap en un select

Tags: html, css, selector

Quería consultar si me pueden ayudar a colocar iconos de bootstrap en los items de un select

```
<select class="form-select" id='nombre1'>
<option value='1'>Texto 1 <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill"></i></option>
<option value='1'>Texto 2 <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill"></i></option>
<option value='1'>Texto 3 <i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill"></i></option>
<select>
```

He probado de varias formas pero no logro que salga nada
Ya tengo cargados los css de bootstrap, y si lo coloco el codigo (`<i class="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill"></i>`) por fuera de un select funciona perfecto

Espero puedan ayudarme
gracias

Comment: solo puedes ponerlo dentro del select, he intentado pero dentro de los inputs no lo he logrado.

Answer (score 1):

En un **option**, segun su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) tan solo se permite:

> Texto con,  eventualmente, caracteres especiales
> (como `&eacute;`).

Tal como sugiere [esta respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805015/how-to-add-icons-in-a-select-using-bootstrap-5-and-bootstrap-icons) puedes tunearlo un poco con un [input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/input-group/) o buscar un caracter [unicode](https://javiergraya.000webhostapp.com/uni.php) que se parezca.

Por otra parte, usando el plugin [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-options), sí parece que se pueda hacer. Dejo un snippet de ejemplo con las dos sintaxis posibles de bootstrap-select para ello:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div>
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-icon="bi bi-apple"> Apple</option>
  <option data-icon="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill">Texto 1</option>
  <option data-icon="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill">Texto 2</option>
  <option data-icon="bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill">Texto 3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-content="Apple <i class='bi bi-apple'></i>">Apple</option>
  <option data-content="Texto 1 <i class='bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill'></i>">Texto 1</option>
  <option data-content="Texto 2 <i class='bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill'></i>">Texto 2</option>
  <option data-content="Texto 3 <i class='bi bi-arrow-down-circle-fill'></i>">Texto 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Eso no es lo que necesito.
el input group es para poner un icono o lo que sea al lado de un input o etiqueta.
Lo que yo quiero es que en cada item del selecto tenga un icono, en particular los iconos de bootstrap

Comment: Pues solo con html no puedes, aunque puedes probar con este plugin: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-options

Comment: he tratado de incluir bootstrap-select pero no logue que funcione ajja

Comment: @JorgePiovano Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con ese plugin funcionando bien en un snippet.